# '$ kubectl create deployment ...' keeps on creating pods on the master node, not the worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3d

Running the below commands...

```
k3d cluster create challenge2 --agents 3 -p "8080:80@loadbalancer

kubectl create deployment k3d-challenge2-agent-0 --image nginx:latest
```

... creates pods on the master node/control plane...:

```
default       k3d-challenge2-agent-0-7894df65f8-c2j6v   0/1    ContainerCreating   0        
  4s     <none>     k3d-challenge2-server-0   <none>           <none>
```

... as indicated by the presence of `k3d-challenge2-server-0`.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to avoid it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I might be seeing something similar (new to Kubernetes). When I run a 'kubectl create deployment ...' it is creating pods automatically that aren't connected to a service and keep failing to run and I can't seem to delete.

Comment: would ypu add output of this command: `for node in $(kubectl get node -oname);do echo "====${node}=====";kubectl describe $node |perl -0777 -nle  '/(?s)(Allocated resources:.*overcommitted..\n)(.*)(?=Events:)/m;print $2' ;done`

Comment: also, for `kubectl describe node |grep -i taint`

Comment: At this moment I don't see that pods not created on agent nodes - you have created deployment with 1 replica. You can increase to 4 number of replicas, as number of your nodes `kubectl scale deployment/k3d-challenge2-agent-0 --replicas=4` and check where new pods will be deployed: `kubectl get po -o wide`